# Getting error when running Android simulator, RN powerd with expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am getting an error when I run npm run

> Execution failed for task ':unimodules-core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

I have done all of the steps shown in other Stackoverflow posts.

my App.json looks like this

```
  "expo": {
    "name": "Unit",
    "slug": "UNIT",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "36.0.0",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android", "web"],
    "version": "1.1.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.unitvpm.unit"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.unitvpm.unit",
      "versionCode": 2
    },
    "entryPoint": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js"
  },
  "displayName": "Unit",
  "name": "Unit"
}
```

I also added `implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5"` to /android/app/build.gradle file

I have no idea what else I need to do. Please help.